# How to add methods to rush (Ruby shell)?

Tags: shell, ruby

I am starting to learn the basics of [rush](http://rush.heroku.com) (ruby shell), and I know it is possible to invoke methods such as `home['foobar.c'].vi`.

However, say I wanted to edit it with *GNU Emacs*, **how do I add a new method** that does that for me, so I can only invoke `home['foobar.c'].emacs`?

P.S. There is a configuration file `env.rb`, in which you can put Ruby code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently from http://rush.heroku.com/handbook/environment, I'm guessing you'd put this into ~/.rush/commands.rb -- modifying the source entry for the vi proc [here](http://rush.heroku.com/rdoc/classes/Rush/Commands.html#M000024)

```
def emacs(*args)
  names = entries.map { |f| f.full_path }.join(' ')
  system "emacs #{names} #{args.join(' ')}"
end
```